# postgresql grouping of data according to different time ranges stored in a table

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I have a table with measurements from temperature sensors, example:

| id | id_device | measured_time (timestamp) | measured_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-07-10 09:00 | 19.90 |

I also have several tariffs with time zones (e.g. 3 time zones: night, empty house and active house):

| time zone | Winter (01/01/2022-31/03/2022 i 01/10/2022-31/12/2022) | Summer (01/04/2022 - 30/09/2022) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. Night | 20:00 - 7:00 | 22:00 - 5:00 |
| 2. Empty house | 10:00 - 17:00 | 10:00 - 17:00 |
| 3. Active house | 7:00 - 10:00 and 17:00-20:00 | 5:00-10:00 and 17:00 - 22:00 |

Saturdays, Sundays and holidays

| time zone | Winter (01/01/2022-31/03/2022 i 01/10/2022-31/12/2022) | Summer (01/04/2022 - 30/09/2022) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. Night | 21:00 - 8:00 | 23:00 - 6:00 |
| 2. Empty house | 12:00 - 15:00 | 12:00 - 15:00 |
| 3. Active house | 8:00 - 12:00 and 15:00-21:00 | 6:00-12:00 and 15:00 - 23:00 |

I need to group measurements data into appropriate time zones. The expected result:

| measured_time | measured_value | zone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-10 09:00 | 19.90 | Active house |
| 2022-07-10 10:00 | 19.90 | Active house |
| 2022-07-10 11:00 | 20.10 | Active house |
| 2022-07-10 12:00 | 20.10 | Active house |
| 2022-07-10 13:00 | 20.50 | Empty house |
| 2022-07-10 14:00 | 20.70 | Empty house |
| 2022-07-10 15:00 | 21.00 | Empty house |
| 2022-07-10 16:00 | 21.00 | Active house |
| 2022-07-10 17:00 | 21.00 | Active house |
| 2022-07-10 18:00 | 21.00 | Active house |
| 2022-07-10 19:00 | 21.00 | Active house |
| 2022-07-10 20:00 | 20.70 | Active house |
| 2022-07-10 21:00 | 20.50 | Active house |
| 2022-07-10 22:00 | 20.40 | Active house |
| 2022-07-10 23:00 | 20.10 | Active house |
| 2022-07-11 00:00 | 20.00 | Night |
| 2022-07-11 01:00 | 19.90 | Night |
| 2022-07-11 02:00 | 19.60 | Night |
| 2022-07-11 03:00 | 19.20 | Night |

The main challenge is to store tariff's time zones well in database. My first idea was to separate time and date to another columns:

```
CREATE TABLE tariff_time_ranges (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    if_tariff int8 NOT NULL,
    hour_from time NOT NULL,
    hour_to time NOT NULL,
    date_from date NOT NULL,
    date_to date NOT NULL
);
```

and check it in query:

```
...
JOIN measurements ON d.device_id = m.id_device AND
(m.measure_time::time > hour_from AND m.measure_time::time <= hour_to 
AND date_from <= m.measure_time AND m.measure_time <= date_to )
```

This solution forces me to rewrite the whole year into time ranges (without overlaps):

| id | if_tariff | id_time_zone | hour_from | hour_to | date_from | date_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 (night) | 23:00 | 00:00 | 2022-07-09 | 2022-07-09 (Summer Saturday) |
| 2 | 1 | 1 (night) | 00:00 | 07:00 | 2022-07-10 | 2022-07-10 (Summer Sunday) |
| 3 | 1 | 3 (active house) | 07:00 | 10:00 | 2022-07-10 | 2022-07-10 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 (empty house) | 10:00 | 15:00 | 2022-07-10 | 2022-07-10 |

What better idea to achieve the intended goal?

Comment: How did you defined your tariffs? As you showed, this seemed to be a bunch of string values. I guess, it is not. Or do you want us to build a proper table/data design for it?

Comment: @S-Man I get tariffs from official documents (from the energy supplier) as presented in the second and third table of my post. I suppose my design for tarif_time_ranges is not the best

Comment: Does this change yearly or something? Is night next year maybe from 22h? Does winter always goes from month 10 to 3 or can this change... All these information can extremely influence a table model...

Comment: @S-Man Thank you for your comments. Each energy supplier has its own tariffs and can change them, but such changes do not occur so I would assume that the time zones of a given tariff are constant.